# How can I get GROUP BY to work the Django ORM where I want all fields and the object

Tags: django, django-orm

I need to group all entries by user and get the count doing something like this:

```
class Promotion(models.Model):
    pass

class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User');
    promotion = models.ForeignKey('Promotion')


def get_uniques(promotion_id):
    promotion = Promotion.objects.get(promotion_id)
    entries = promotion.entry_set.annotate(Count('user'))
    return entries
```

However it's returning the same user multiple times. I've also tried the following after looking around StackOverflow, and it seem to be doing something other than what I want:

```
promotion.entry_set.annotate(Count('user')).order_by('user')[:10]
promotion.entry_set.all().values('user').annotate(entry_count=Count('user')).order_by()
Entry.objects.filter(promotion=promotion).annotate(Count('user')).order_by('user')
```

Basically I'm trying to do this, giving me an Entry object for each user:

```
Entry.objects.raw("""
    SELECT *
    FROM promotion_entry
    WHERE promotion_id = %s
    GROUP BY user_id""", (promotion_id,))
```

Then I'll perform a second query to get the entry count, still not ideal. Can I do a GROUP BY without raw?

There seem to be a ticket that would let me do what I want in the future over on the bugtracker by enabling `DISTINCT ON`: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6422

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count entries for each user use:

```
promotion.entry_set.all().values('user').annotate(entry_count=Count('id')).order_by()
```

If you want some entry for each user use:

```
promotion.entry_set.all().values('user').annotate(entry_id=Max('id')).order_by()
```

This will give you `id`'s of entries, use `__in` to get objects themselves.

Comment: That doesn't quite do what I want. It's the equivalent of `SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM giveaways_entry WHERE promotion_id = 57 GROUP BY user_id;`

Comment: @KitSunde And what do you want to get? All entries for each user or count of entries for each user? If second - see my answer, if first - it's not done with `GROUP BY` (`order_by` + `itertools.regroup` will do the trick).

Comment: I was being a bit ambiguous, I agree. I want to have one Entry object for each user, but not more than one. I'll handle the count separately since it's not part of the model, and it would seem like Django wouldn't just add it.

Wouldn't itertools.regroup iterate over every matched row? This is what I've been trying to avoid, previously the code I had did an all() and iterated over the queryset filtering out already seen users, but since I want to do pagination I would rather have the correct slice of the result since the query set can get quite large.

Comment: @KitSunde "I want to have one Entry object for each user" - what object? Any or satisfying some criteria (e.g. latest)?

Comment: Just any single one, doesn't matter if it's the last Entry or the first for that user, in my use case.